# fillPolygon slows down my application tremendously

Tags: java, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I'm creating a java implantation of http://alteredqualia.com/visualization/evolve/, as a hobby project. I'm using HW-accelerated Graphics2D to draw the polygons on a bufferedImage, which works, but the calling of fillPolygon() so many times cripples the application in terms of speed.

So now my question is: Is there any way to speed up this process?

```
private BufferedImage createImage() //Gets called once
{
    BufferedImage           bImage  = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
                            bImage.setAccelerationPriority(1);
    Graphics2D              g2d     = (Graphics2D) bImage.getGraphics();
                            g2d.setRenderingHint(
                                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                            g2d.setRenderingHint(
                                RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING,
                                RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_SPEED);
    this.g2d = g2d;

    return bImage;
}
private void reDraw() //Gets called every frame
{
    drawBackground(g2d);

    for(int i = 0; i < polygonList.getLength(); i++)
    {
        polygonList.get(i).draw(g2d);
    }
}
public void draw(Graphics2D g2d)
{
    if(rgba[3] != 0f)
    {
        g2d.setColor(new Color(rgba[0], rgba[1], rgba[2], rgba[3]));
        g2d.fillPolygon(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Create the color outside the draw, and maybe without floats.

Comment: `to draw the polygons on a bufferedImage,` - if you are drawing to a BufferedImage then you only need to do that once. Then you can just use the Graphics.drawImage(...) method to paint the BufferedImage.

Comment: What's the shape of your polygon? If you can easily break it down to triangles on your end and use those every frame, you might get a bit of a boost.

Comment: @camickr I don't understand, how would I draw (for example) 50 polygons at once?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about optimizing working code. Ask on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `I don't understand, how would I draw (for example) 50 polygons at once?` you have a loop. Drawing 50 polygons is not a problem, so I'm not really sure what you are worried about. I have drawn 5,000 moving circles every 75ms without a problem. However, what I was suggesting is that if you think the drawPolygon(...) method is slow then you can initially create 50 individual BufferedImages and then create a loop that just paints the BufferedImages. This will be faster because it would just copy the pixels from the BufferedImage without doing any math calculation for the actual polygon.

Comment: Or if you have a static image that consists of 50 polygons, then you paint all 50 polygons to the BufferedImage once, and then just repaint the BufferedImage as required. I suggest you post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) if you need more help.

Comment: Assuming that transparency is essential for your goal, the first optimization would be to disable Anti-Aliasing (as Lee Allan already suggested). Apart from that, it might help to know how many vertices these polygons have, or whether you can make any assumptions (e.g. whether they are always convex). Using LWGL or JOGL (OpenGL in general) will certainly help, but the effort of an OpenGL >=3.2 application compared to a Swing application will be tremendous.

Answer (score 0):

With the use of java.awt.Graphics there is not much you can do on your end to improve performance except the usual optimizations of Java (reducing object creation and function calls etc). You can however choose how it renders on its end with the `RenderHint`s as I see you are doing; I would suggest you set *all* the hints to speed including disabling antialiasing because that is actually one of the biggest hits.

Apart from that I can see you are using some array of what I can assume are ints and creating a colour with them, now I'm not sure what class this is from (assuming it's all from one class, please correct me) - nethertheless the `if` statement could be a return instead (that wont help much), and you should cache this Colour when it changes, I suggest not using the rgba array and using one global Color instance and then use `getRed/Green/Blue` if you ever need them.

If you would like more advice you can move this to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. You mentioned how awt Graphics is inherently slow, is there perhaps a different package which offers better performance, possibly at the price of convenience?

Comment: @user1870238 The only other graphics API I have used is LWJGL - great for reducing graphics load to nearly nothing but I dont know how to take the final rendered image as a BufferedImage unfortunately.